# Why can't std::is_permutation act between two different types of data?

Tags: c++11, lambda, stl

Suppose I have a vector of integers and of strings, and I want to compare whether they have equivalent elements, without consideration of order. Ultimately, I'm asking if the integer vector is a permutation of the string vector (or vice versa). I'd like to be able to just call is_permutation, specify a binary predicate that allows me to compare the two, and move on with my life. eg:

```
bool checkIntStringComparison( const std::vector<int>& intVec,
                 const std::vector<std::string>& stringVec,
                 const std::map<int, std::string>& intStringMap){
  return std::is_permutation<std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator>(
        intVec.cbegin(), intVec.cend(), stringVec.cbegin(), [&intStringMap](const int& i, const std::string& string){
    return string == intStringMap.at(i);
  });
}
```

But trying to compile this (in gcc) returns an error message that boils down to:

> no match for call to *stuff*::< lambda(const int&, const string& >)(const std::_cxx11::basic_string&, const int&)

see how it switches the calling signature from the lambda's? If I switch them around, the signature switches itself the other way.

Digging around about this error, it seems that the standard specifies for std::is_permutation that ForwardIterator1 and 2 must be the same type. So I understand the compiler error in that regard. But why should it be this way? If I provide a binary predicate that allows me to compare the two (or if we had previously defined some equality operator between the two?), isn't the real core of the algorithm just searching through container 1 to make sure all its elements are in container 2 uniquely?

Comment: How, exactly, will it help you if you knew why this was the case?  Why not ask "I have discovered that is_permutation only works on identical iterator types for the two sequences.  I want to do it on non-identical iterator types.  How can I do this?"  As written, answerers can delve into ancient standardization discussions and/or standard history and come up with some information about why this was made, but I suspect the answer is "because KISS".

Comment: Because I might learn something useful about the kinds of assumptions the standard template library makes when I use it? Because it's more helpful, to me at least, to understand the theory of why a thing is a way than it is to just ask someone to fix my problem for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that an element can occur more than once. That means that the predicate needs to be able to not only compare the elements of the first range to the elements of the second range, but to compare the elements of the first range to themselves:

```
if (size(range1) != size(range2))
    return false;
for (auto const& x1 : range1)
    if (count_if(range1, [&](auto const& y1) { return pred(x1, y1); }) !=
        count_if(range2, [&](auto const& y2) { return pred(x1, y2); }))
        return false;
return true;
```

Since it's relatively tricky to create a function object that takes two distinct signatures, and passing two predicates would be confusing, the easiest option was to specify that both ranges must have the same value type.

Your options are:

- Wrap one range (or both) in a transform that gives the same value type (e.g. use Boost.Adaptors.Transformed);
- Write your own implementation of std::is_permutation (e.g. copying the example implementation on cppreference);
- Actually, note that the gcc (i.e. libstdc++) implementation does not enforce that the value types are the same; it just requires several signatures which you'd have to provide anyway, so write a polymorphic predicate as e.g. a function object or a polymorphic lambda, or with parameter types convertible from both range value types (e.g. in your case `boost::variant<int, string>` - ugly, but probably not that bad). This is non-portable, as another implementation might choose to enforce that requirement.

Comment: thanks, I can appreciate how this specifically happens, but isn't that ultimately still just an implementation detail causing a restriction? Like instead of comparing counts of elements, (following point 2 about writing ones own implementation; in pseudocode):
`vec<int> usedIndices;
for(string : stringVec){ bool flag(false);  for(index i : intVec.size){if (i not in usedIndices & string = intStringMap.at(i) ) { flag=true; usedIndices.append(i)}  } if !flag return false; } return true`

Comment: @shavera you're correct that this is an implementation detail, but consider that (a) the standard algorithms are well-known in computer science literature, so most library implementations will use the same or similar algorithm, and (b) if there are alternate implementations they may have *more* restrictions, so relaxing the requirements could prevent the use of the most efficient implementation. Also note that your proposed algorithm requires memory allocation, and the standard avoids that except where absolutely necessary (e.g. in `stable_sort`).

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of detail that helps me understand why things are the way they are

Answer (score 0):

Late answer. It seems that the custom predicate must implement all comparison operators between all types. For example (real code wouldn't use 'at' but 'find' and check the iterator):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Compare
{
   explicit Compare(const std::map<int, std::string>* pIntStringMap)
      : m_pIntStringMap(pIntStringMap)
   {
   }

   bool operator() (int n1, int n2) const
   {
      return n1 == n2;
   }

   bool operator() (const std::string& rstr1, const std::string& rstr2) const
   {
      return rstr1 == rstr2;
   }

   bool operator() (int n, const std::string& rstr) const
   {
      return rstr == m_pIntStringMap->at(n);
   }

   bool operator() (const std::string& rstr, int n) const
   {
      return m_pIntStringMap->at(n) == rstr;
   }

private:
   const std::map<int, std::string>* m_pIntStringMap;
};


bool checkIntStringComparison(const std::vector<int>& rvecInt,
                              const std::vector<std::string>& rvecString,
                              const std::map<int, std::string>& rmapIntString)
{
   return std::is_permutation(rvecInt.cbegin(), rvecInt.cend(), 
                              rvecString.cbegin(), rvecString.cend(),
                              Compare{&rmapIntString}
                              );
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   const std::vector<int>           vec1          = { 1, 2, 3 };
   const std::vector<std::string>   vec2          = { "2", "1", "3"};
   const std::map<int, std::string> mapIntString  = { {1, "1"}, {2, "2"}, {3, "3"} };

   const bool bOk = checkIntStringComparison(vec1, vec2, mapIntString);

   return bOk ? 0 : -1;
}
```